Does a continuous piecewise-affine function preserve the convexity of a set?
Consider a convex set $C\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ in the $n$-dimensional real vector space, and a continuous piecewise-affine function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$. Is the set $f(C) = \{y ~|~ y = f(x),~ x\in C \}$ still convex?
For a "globally" (correct me if this is not the proper term) affine function $f'$, we can take advantage of its properties $f'(ax) = af'(x)$ for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'(x_1 + x_2) = f'(x_1) + f'(x_2)$. Then, for any $x_1, x_2 \in C$, we have
$$ \theta f'(x_1) + (1 - \theta) f'(x_2) = f'(\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2), ~ \theta\in[0, 1];$$
since $\theta x_1 + (1-\theta) x_2 \in C$, we have $ \theta f'(x_1) + (1 - \theta) f'(x_2) \in f'(C)$ and hence $f'$ preserves convexity.
However, for a continuous piecewise-affine function $f$, we don't have $f(ax) = af(x)$. Does that mean $f$ does not preserve convexity, or should the proof be attempted from a different direction?
I'm considering a particular form of the continuous piecewise-affine functions. They have the "quadrants" as their pieces; i.e., within each "piece," each dimension has the same sign.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

@JoséCarlosSantos Thanks! I've updated the post and hope it is better now.

Just to note, bending a piece of wire (an interval, convex) into an L in the plane (not convex), can be done in a piecewise affine way.

@AndrewD.Hwang In point of fact, since for $m=1$ a PL function sends convex sets to convex sets if and only if it's linear, by restricting to lines and considering the appropriate things at the boundaries you should have that the same claim holds for all $m$.

Consider $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}(x,y)&\text{if }x<0\\ (x,y-x)&\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}$$ Then $f([-1,1]\times[0,1])$ is not convex.
